# Numeric filters not work, =,<,> operator filters not work

Tags: metabase

I have setup metabase version 0.31 and connect druid broker node for quring. But when i try to do numeric filters (Long, int, double column types), =,<,> operating filters not work.

Please help me to fixed this issue.

Comment: We have the same issue, I reported it to Metabase on Github yesterday https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/10935 I would appreciate you upvoting and/or commenting it on Github so it gains more attention :)